# An ODE related to the Riccati equation.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'd like to solve the ODE
\begin{equation}
y_{xx}+(y_{x})^2+y\sqrt{1+y^2}=0,\\
\end{equation}
where $y=y(x)$. By letting $y_x(x)=z(x)$, the first two terms become $z_x+z^2$, which reminds me of the Riccati equation.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riccati_equation

However, the last term $y\sqrt{1+y^2}$ becomes something related to $\int z\,dx$. Any other idea to start with proving the existence of solutions (or an exact solution is available?)? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Substituting $y' =p=p(y)$ we get $y'' =p'(y)y' =p'p$ we get $$p'p +p^2 +y\sqrt{1+y^2}=0$$ then substituting $p^2 =v $ we get $\frac{v'}{2} =p'p$ hence $$\frac{v'}{2} +v +y\sqrt{1+y^2}=0,$$

Comment: Thanks for your idea. Using integrating factor, it seems we are not able to write down the solution $v=v(y)$ explicitly for the last equation?